# Node processes keep restarting

Tags: process, kill, node.js

I'm currently running a few node processes on PM2, but when I stop them with pm2, then run `ps -ef | grep node`, it shows the processes as still running.

One of them is an express application that listens on the port the original process did, but most requests end with `Cannot GET /something`. Oddly, some requests do respond.

Doing `pkill -9 process_name` kills that process, but when I list the processes again it shows it as having restarted with a higher PID.

I've tried doing `pm2 kill` and then killing the processes, but they keep coming back.

Comment: I don't suppose your node processes are running under some sort of supervisor program, like [forever](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74328/117549) (or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42743/117549))?

Comment: Oh, never mind my ignorance, apparently [pm2 is such a supervisor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)

Comment: I've tried killing pm2 and they still restart.